# Problema com Pytest

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando aplicar o pytest em um projeto que utiliza a Fórmula de Bhaskara, pois está dando dando erro e não estou conseguindo resolver. 
A seguida irão os códigos com o erro. 
Obrigado.

```
import math

class Bhaskara:

    def delta(self, a, b, c):
        return b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

    def calcula_raizes(self, a, b, c):
        d = self.delta(a, b, c)
        if d == 0:
            raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
            return 1, raiz1
        else:
            if d < 0:
                return 0
            else:
                raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
                raiz2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
                return 2, raiz1, raiz2

import Bhaskara

import pytest

class Test_Bhaskara:

    @pytest.fixture
    def b(self):
        return Bhaskara.Bhaskara()

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada, saida", [
            ((1, 0, 0), (1, 0,)),
            ((1, -5, 6), (2, 3, 2)),
            ((10, 10, 10), (0,)),
            ((10, 20, 10), (1, -1))
        ])

    def testa_bhaskara(self, entrada, saida):
        b = Bhaskara()
        assert b.calcula_raizes(entrada) == saida
```

Saída do pytest

```
___ Test_Bhaskara.testa_bhaskara[entrada3-saida3] ___

self = <Test_Bhaskara.Test_Bhaskara instance at 0x7f1ea0453680>
entrada = (10, 20, 10), saida = (1, -1)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada, saida", [
            [(1, 0, 0,), (1, 0,)],
            [(1, -5, 6,), (2, 3, 2,)],
            [(10, 10, 10,), (0,)],
            [(10, 20, 10,), (1, -1,)]
        ])

def testa_bhaskara(self, entrada, saida):
    b = Bhaskara()
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Test_Bhaskara.py:14: TypeError
========= 4 failed in 0.04 seconds =========
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from Bhaskara import Bhaskara
```

Aí ele carregará a classe "Bhaskara" dentro de "Bhaskara.py".

Aliás, o método calcula_raizes() está errado pois ele espera **trẽs** valores numéricos e você está mandando **uma** tupla para ele. Para não mexer naquilo que você já montou 
para os testes, tente algo assim:

```
def calcula_raizes(self, valores):
    (a, b, c) = valores
    d = self.delta(a, b, c)
    ...
```

Que deverá resolver.